# Given a starting state $X_0$, what is the probability of $\mathbb P\{ X_5 = A | X_4=B\}$ and $\mathbb P\{ X_4 = B | X_5=A\}$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X_n$ be a Markov chain with state space $S= \{A,B,C\}$ and transition matrix $P = [p_{ij}]$, where $i,j \in S$ and
\begin{equation*}
P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1/4 & 1/2 & 1/4 \\
1/4 & 1/4 & 1/2 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Suppose that $X_0 = C$.

By homogeneity of Markov Chain, is $\mathbb P( X_5 = A | X_4=B) = \mathbb P(X_1 = A | X_0 = B) = p_{BA}$?

And $\mathbb P( X_4 = B | X_5=A) = P(X_4 = B) = \mathbb P(X_4 =B| X_0 = C) = (0,0,1) \times P^4 \times (0,1,0)^T$?

Comment: I don't see why the first equation in the last sentence should hold. Don't you want to apply Bayes' Theorem? or, at any rate, the definition of conditional probability?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I thought about using Bayes' Theorem, but I am not sure if I overthought about that. So I think that by homogeneity of Markov Chain, we have that for all times $t$, $\mathbb P_{ij} = \mathbb P(X_{t+1} = j | X_t = i)$. So, $P_{ij} = \mathbb P(X_{t+1} = j | X_t = i) = \mathbb P(X_1= j | X_0 = i)$

Comment: But that's not what you are using when you write $\mathbb P( X_4 = B | X_5=A) = P(X_4 = B)$, is it? Don't you want $P(r|s)=P(r\wedge s)/P(s)=(P(s|r)P(r))/P(s)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think in $\mathbb P( X_4 = B | X_5=A)$, the information of $X_5$ does not affect the value of $X_4$ since $X_4$ happens before $X_5$. So, knowing $X_5$ does not help in calculating the probability of $X_4 = B$ because any state at $X_4$ can go to $X_5=A$. Am I right?

Comment: Imagine a situation where $X_{t+1}=A$ only happens when $X_t=B$. Then $P(X_4=B|X_5=A)=1$, but $P(X_4=B)$ need not be $1$. E.g., suppose that when you're in state $A$, you always go to state $B$, and when you're in state $B$, half the time you go to state $A$, half the time you stay in state $B$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your example seems right, but let's fix a matrix to make thing clearer. I added a matrix $P$ in the question. Can we discuss this question based on this matrix? Is my reasoning correct with this transition matrix $P$.

Comment: Calculate $P(X_4=B|X_5=A)$ using the formula I wrote up, and calculate $P(X_4=B)$, and see whether they are equal.